# What is the name of a city management(group or team) in English?

Tags: word-request

As far as I know, most of the countries in the world use "city government" to this end and some in the US use "city council".

But lately when visiting Bangladesh, a country in south Asia that is a former colony of Britain and part of the old India, I saw many official documents affixed with the sign of "city corporation" and the public properties on the street like the rubbish can marked with the same words.

My reaction was like, What is it? A city now becomes a company? I asked some local people but they either do not know English or they do not really know it means because such a name has existed for a long time.

So far I do not find any satisfying answer to that question in my search.

So is "city corporation" the right name in English for a city management team?

Comment: This is definitely not the term used in the United States, at least nowhere that I've ever heard of. But we *do* speak of an "incorporated" city and the "unincorporated" area outside the city (or we can, if the system is set up that way; in many states there is no such thing as an unincorporated area). See also the Wikipedia article on "[municipal corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipal_corporation)."

Answer (score 1):

"Corporation" is a correct legal term for a local government entity.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corporation) lists a definition as *The municipal governing body of a borough or city.*

[The term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipal_corporation) seems to be used in several countries

In everyday language, people would refer to the appropriate administration level such as "city government" or "mayor's office".

Comment: My home city (in the UK) now has a City Council, but the terminology for local government has changed and some decades ago it had a Corporation.

Comment: @KateBunting - my partner from Wigan's father called tap water 'Corporation pop'.